# Consulta iterativa con permisos

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Tengo dos tablas `jerarquia` y `permisos`, donde jerarquia tiene un ID, un ID_PADRE (apuntando a la misma tabla hacia un nodo padre) y una DESCRIPCION propia del nodo. La tabla permisos tiene un ID_OPERADOR (id del usuario que esta logueado en el sistema), ID_NODO (id del nodo para el que le estoy especificando permisos, foranea a la tabla `jerarquia`) y R (que es un BIT que indica si tiene permisos de lectura), **no todos los nodos tienen un permiso especificado, pueden haber nodos que no aparezcan en la tabla permisos**

Estoy haciendo una consulta que te trae los nodos que coinciden con un criterio e iteratívamente trae a los nodos superiores de cada rama, ese algoritmo me funcionaba bien, pero ahora que se agregó la tabla de permisos si un nodo tiene R = 0 (es decir, que tiene permisos de lectura denegado) toda la rama que cuelga de él no debe verse. Hasta el momento tengo esta consulta, pero la verdad que estoy bastante estancado:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @TablaFiltrada TABLE (
    ID INT,
    ID_PADRE INT,
    DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(200),
    R BIT
)

DECLARE @Rows INT

INSERT INTO @TablaFiltrada (ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, R)
SELECT J1.ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, P.R
FROM jerarquia J1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PERMISOS WHERE ID_OPERADOR = 1002) P ON J1.ID = P.ID_NODO
WHERE DESCRIPCION LIKE 'keyword' AND (R IS NULL OR R = 1)

SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TablaFiltrada (ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, R)
    SELECT P2.ID, P2.ID_PADRE, P2.DESCRIPCION, P.R
    FROM jerarquia P2
    INNER JOIN @TablaFiltrada P1 ON P2.ID = P1.ID_PADRE
    LEFT JOIN @TablaFiltrada P3 ON P3.ID = P2.ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PERMISOS WHERE ID_OPERADOR = 1002) P ON P2.ID = P.ID_NODO
    WHERE P3.ID IS NULL

    SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT -- Sigo iterando

END

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @TablaFiltrada
WHERE R IS NULL OR R = 1
ORDER BY DESCRIPCION
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: La pregunta se ve interesante. Puedes postear algunos datos de ejemplo para la tabla `jerarquia` y `permisos`?, también etiqueta la versión de SQL Server que estás usando por favor

Comment: Hola! Ahí añadí la versión! Gracias

Comment: Si un usuario tiene permiso a un nodo, significa que a todos los niveles inferiores también?, o debe ser explícito el permiso por nodo?.

Comment: Excelente pregunta, los permisos se heredan, no debe ser explicito por cada nodo. En caso de encontrar un nodo con permiso de lectura denegados (R = 0) la rama que cuelga de el, es decir, todos sus nodos hijos, deben ser eliminados del resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí encontré una manera que no se si es la mejor posible, pero funciona bien:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
-- Tabla con el resultado final
DECLARE @TablaFiltrada TABLE (
    ID INT,
    ID_PADRE INT,
    DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(200),
    R BIT
)
-- Declaro la tabla que va a almacenar los ID de nodos que no tienen permisos de lectura
DECLARE @TablaDenegados TABLE (
    ID INT,
    ID_PADRE INT
)

DECLARE @Rows INT, @IdOperador INT, @EsSuperAdmin BIT

SET @IdOperador = :idOperador
SET @EsSuperAdmin = (SELECT ES_SUPERADMIN FROM V_SYS_OPERADOR WHERE ID_OPERADOR = @IdOperador)

-- Cargo los nodos encontrados
INSERT INTO @TablaFiltrada (ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, R)
SELECT J1.ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, P.R,
FROM jerarquia J1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PERMISOS WHERE ID_OPERADOR = @IdOperador) P ON J1.ID = P.ID_NODO
    WHERE DESCRIPCION LIKE :palabrasClaves AND (R IS NULL OR R = 1)

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TablaFiltrada (ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION, R)
    SELECT P2.ID, P2.ID_PADRE, P2.DESCRIPCION, P.R
    FROM jerarquia P2
        INNER JOIN @TablaFiltrada P1 ON P2.ID = P1.ID_PADRE
        LEFT JOIN @TablaFiltrada P3 ON P3.ID = P2.ID
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM PERMISOS WHERE ID_OPERADOR = @IdOperador) P ON P2.ID = P.ID_NODO
    WHERE P3.ID IS NULL

    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT -- Sigo iterando

END

-- Cargo los nodos con permisos de lectura denegada
INSERT INTO @TablaDenegados
SELECT DISTINCT(ID), ID_PADRE FROM @TablaFiltrada WHERE @EsSuperAdmin = 0 AND (NIVEL_NODO >=2 AND R = 0)

SET @Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TablaDenegados)

-- Almaceno toda la rama en la Tabla de denegados
WHILE @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @TablaDenegados (P2.ID, P2.ID_PADRE)
    SELECT  P2.ID, P2.ID_PADRE
        FROM    @TablaDenegados P1
        INNER JOIN @TablaFiltrada P2
            ON P2.ID_PADRE = P1.ID
        LEFT JOIN @TablaDenegados P3
            ON P3.ID = P2.ID
    WHERE P3.ID IS NULL

    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT -- Sigo iterando

END

-- Selecciono los que finalmente tienen los permisos adecuados
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @TablaFiltrada
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @TablaDenegados)
ORDER BY DESCRIPCION
```

Answer (score 1):

Si duda, como dice Lamak es una pregunta interesante, te cuento una forma de resolverlo, tal vez no sea la más óptima y tiene algunas limitaciones:

- Cada "nivel" puede tener hasta 9999 elementos (se puede modificar eventualmente esto)
- Se puede manejar una cantidad máxima de ramas de la longitud de `LEN(VARCHAR(MAX)) / 4`

Supongamos que tenemos una Jerarquía completa como la siguiente:

```
ID      DESCRIPCION
======= ============================
1,00    Accesorios para celulares
3,00        Baterías
4,00            Genericas
5,00            Originales
6,00        Protectores
7,00            Plásticos
8,00            Vidrio
2,00    Celulares
9,00        Gama Alta
10,00           Iphone 6
11,00           Samsung S8
12,00       Gama Media
13,00   Accesorios PC
14,00       Teclados
15,00       Monitores
```

Es un ejemplo tonto de categorías para clasificar un producto, ahora supongamos que queremos "deshabilitrar" toda la rama de "Celulares", es decir "Celulares", "Gama Alta", "Iphone 6", etc pero deshabilitando únicamente el nivel "Celulares".

```
DECLARE  @TablaFiltrada TABLE 
(
    ID      INT,
    NODO            VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @Jerarquia TABLE (
        ID              INT,
        ID_PADRE        INT,
    DESCRIPCION     NVARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @Permisos TABLE (
    ID              INT,
    R           BIT
)

INSERT INTO @Jerarquia(ID, ID_PADRE, DESCRIPCION)
VALUES ( 1, NULL, 'Accesorios para celulares'),
       ( 2, NULL, 'Celulares'),
       ( 3,    1, 'Baterías'),
       ( 4,    3, 'Genericas'),
       ( 5,    3, 'Originales'),
       ( 6,    1, 'Protectores'),
       ( 7,    6, 'Plásticos'),
       ( 8,    6, 'Vidrio'),
       ( 9,    2, 'Gama Alta'),
       (10,    9, 'Iphone 6'),
       (11,    9, 'Samsung S8'),
       (12,    2, 'Gama Media'),
       (13, NULL, 'Accesorios PC'),
       (14,   13, 'Teclados'),
       (15,   13, 'Monitores')

-- SOLO "Celulares" TIENE EL FLAG APAGADO
INSERT INTO @Permisos (Id, R)
    VALUES (2, 0)

SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @Rows INT

INSERT INTO  @TablaFiltrada (ID, nodo)
SELECT  ID,
    RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID),4)
    FROM @Jerarquia
    WHERE ID_PADRE IS NULL

SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO  @TablaFiltrada (ID, nodo)
    SELECT  J.ID,
        N.Nodo + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, J.ID),4)
        FROM @Jerarquia J
        INNER JOIN @Jerarquia P
            ON P.ID = J.ID_PADRE
        INNER JOIN  @TablaFiltrada N
            ON J.ID_PADRE = N.ID
        WHERE J.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM  @TablaFiltrada)

    SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT -- Sigo iterando

END

SELECT  J.ID,
    SPACE(LEN(N.NODO)-4) + J.DESCRIPCION
    -- CASE WHEN NP.NODO IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'R'
    FROM  @TablaFiltrada N
    INNER JOIN @Jerarquia J
        ON N.ID = J.ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT N1.nodo
            FROM  @TablaFiltrada N1
            INNER JOIN @Permisos P
                ON P.ID = N1.ID
            WHERE P.R = 0
        ) NP
        ON LEFT(N.nodo, LEN(NP.nodo)) = NP.nodo
    WHERE NP.NODO IS NULL
    ORDER BY N.NODO
```

La salida:

```
ID      DESCRIPCION
======= ============================
1,00    Accesorios para celulares
3,00        Baterías
4,00            Genericas
5,00            Originales
6,00        Protectores
7,00            Plásticos
8,00            Vidrio
13,00   Accesorios PC
14,00       Teclados
15,00       Monitores
```

Lo esencial de este método es generar un campo `nodo` que es la representación jerárquica del "árbol", algo como esto:

```
ID      nodo
======= ============================
1,00    0001
3,00    00010003
4,00    000100030004
5,00    000100030005
6,00    00010006
7,00    000100060007
8,00    000100060008
2,00    0002
9,00    00020009
10,00   000200090010
11,00   000200090011
12,00   00020012
13,00   0013
14,00   00130014
15,00   00130015
```

Así queda más claro que si solo tenemos el `ID=2` como deshabilitado tan solo actualizando los registros cuyo `LEFT(nodo,LEN(nodo)) = '0002'` estaremos deshabilitando toda la rama. La forma de crear los nodos la podemos llegar a modificar, a mi personalmente me gusta verla así por que es útil para ordenar, pero se podrían crear los nodos concatenando cada `id`, por ejemplo `2|9|11` y tendríamos más flexibilidad en cuanto a cantidad de estos.

Comment: Gracias por responder! El Lunes a primera hora prueba en el entorno que tengo y aviso! Gracias nuevamente! Saludoos

Comment: Hola, lamentablemente esta implementación no me sirve ya que no puedo cambiar la estructura de la tabla. Pude solucionar el problema y en cuanto pueda publiquo como pude resolverlo. Gracias y saludos!